# How to set different frame rate for each animation in jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, frame-rate

I know the **frame rate** in jQuery could be set through `jQuery.fx.interval`. 
However, it applies to **all** the jQuery internal animate function such as `slideDown`, `fadeIn` and `animate`etc.

I want to set frame rate for each `animate()`, how could I archieve that?

Answer (score 1):

From the [API documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.interval/):

> Since jQuery uses one global interval, no animation should be running or all animations should stop for the change of this property to take effect.
>
> Note: `jQuery.fx.interval` currently has no effect in browsers that support the requestAnimationFrame property, such as Google Chrome 11. This behavior is subject to change in a future release.

I take from this that you cannot set the frame rate for an individual `animate` call, unless you were willing to have no animations until that one had completed, and even then you can't guarantee the behaviour. It's probably best to leave the setting alone.

Comment: So to clarify, jQuery uses something like this: `window.setInterval(incrementAllAnimations, jQuery.fx.interval) ` so it's just not possible to change it.

Comment: @NathanMacInnes [Yes, almost exactly.](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js#L457)

Answer (score 0):

You can change this by using [fx.interval](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.interval/). Like this:

```
jQuery.fx.interval = 100;

$("input").click(function(){
  $("div").toggle( 3000 );
});
```

Although it says in the documentation that:

*jQuery.fx.interval currently has no effect in browsers that support the requestAnimationFrame property, such as Google Chrome 11. This behavior is subject to change in a future release.*

Comment: I already stated it in my post. I want to set 'per animate' frame rate. This answer is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: But if you make the change directly before you call the particular animate, you can sort of do this.  I think you're out of luck if you have multiple animations running at once, however.